# Java trying to fill int array with unique numbers

Tags: java, arrays, int, unique, infinite-loop

I'm new on this site and i've got very poor english, forgive me for this.

I have a problem with my function:

```
public void generate(int[] array) {
    int i=0;
    boolean isvalid=true;
    while (i < 5) {
        int rng = (int)(Math.random()%100*100);
        for (int j=0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (array[j] == rng) {
                isvalid=false;
                System.out.println("duplicate: "+rng);
            }
        }
        if (isvalid) {
            array[i]=rng;
            System.out.println(rng);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to fill up a 5 size int array with unique random numbers between 0 and 100. This is work, but sometimes bugging, and starting an endless loop, and for some reason my compiler (netbeans) cant generate a new random number, just loop some.
For ex:

```
duplicate 62
duplicate 62
duplicate 64
duplicate 97
duplicate 97
duplicate 64
duplicate 97
duplicate 62
duplicate 64
duplicate 62
duplicate 64
duplicate 62
duplicate 97
duplicate 97
duplicate 56
duplicate 97
duplicate 62
duplicate 56
duplicate 56
duplicate 56
duplicate 64
duplicate 56
duplicate 62
duplicate 56
```

Someone have any usefull tips for my problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once `isvalid = false;` it is never `true` again and therefore you get an infinite loop because you don't increment `i` in that case (quick-fix should be to `isvalid = true` inside the `while`).

Comment: Omg... At least im tired... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you another approach of generating these numbers.

First you create a `List` with all the numbers from `1` to `100`. Then you just select random numbers from the `list` and put them in your array

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100)
             .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

int[] randomArray = new int[100];
Random random = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Integer randomIndex = random.nextInt(list.size());
    randomArray[i] = list.get(randomIndex);
    list.remove(randomIndex);
}
```

This way you are guaranteed that in one iteration you will obtain the needed array, without useless random calls.

Answer (score 1):

Use the facilities Java 8 offers you: Use an infinite stream of random integers between 0 and 100, then distinct, then limit to 5. Since this is homework I think you ought to make some effort so I wont post the few lines required.

Answer (score 0):

```
private List getRandomNumberList(){
    List<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<>();
    while (alist.size() < 5){
        // for numbers from 0 to 100 use factor 101
        int number = (int) (Math.random() * 101);
        if (!alist.contains(number)){
            alist.add(number);
        }
    }
    return alist;
}
```